# Angular: ReactiveForm iterate on embedded controForm in a controlForm

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In a component at the typescript level, I created a form that contains a ControlForm that contains others, and I want to iterate it without success.

I would like to create an HTML (checkbox) element for each iteration on the controlForm 'test' and I would like to inject the name of each ControlForm child into each checkbox.

Here's the form:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
      this.fcTest = this.form.controls.test.value;
    }

  protected buildForm(): void {
    // Form controls
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      allowancesUntil90: [0, [Validators.required]],
      test: this.formBuilder.group({
        1: [false],
        2: [false],
        3: [false],
        4: [false],
        5: [false],
        6: [false]
      }, { validators: []})
    });
  }
```

And in the template:

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of fcTest | keyvalue">
    <amp-check-box [formControl] = form.controls.item ></amp-check-box>
  </div>
```

I have the following error with this code : Argument type FormControl is not assignable to parameter type null

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#group) on `formBuilder`, the `group()` method:

> Construct a new FormGroup instance. Accepts a single generic argument, which is an object containing all the keys and corresponding inner control types

This means that inside a `FormGroup` instance, all the keys should be either a `FormControl`, a `FormGroup` or a `FormArray`. (in your case you are using a `formControl` in the `.html` so you need a `FormControl`)

In your snippet, all the values that you are passing to the keys in the `group()` method are an array of boolean. You may want to have values that are instances of `FormControl` like an start incrementation from 0 (as index in arrays start with 0):

```js
test: this.formBuilder.group({
  0: this.formBuilder.control(false),
  1: this.formBuilder.control(false),
  2: this.formBuilder.control(false),
  3: this.formBuilder.control(false),
  4: this.formBuilder.control(false),
  5: this.formBuilder.control(false)
}
```

Next, `fcTest` should be a control, not the value of the control. So change `ngOnInit` to this :

```js
this.fcTest = this.form.controls.test
```

Then, another issue is located in your `.html` file:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of fcTest | keyvalue">
    <amp-check-box [formControl] = form.controls.item ></amp-check-box>
</div>
```

You want to acces the properties `0,1,2...5` defined in your `.ts` file.

What you may want is:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of fcTest; let fcTestIndex=index">
    <amp-check-box [formControl]=form.controls[fcTestIndex]></amp-check-box>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer but it doesn't seem to solve the problem. Maybe I made a mistake. I’ll look

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your buildForm you are Creating nested form groups.

The first thing you need to add your nested group name **test**
into your

```
<div formGroupName="test">
        <div   *ngFor="let item of fcTest | keyvalue">
        <amp-check-box [formControl] = form.controls[item.key] ></amp-check-box>
      </div>
</div>
```

tag [click here to see how to add](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-nested-form-groups)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but stll doesn't work with the same error message.

Comment: Then please put your code  on live  then we can figure Out What's going on With this